# Finding a string in a row and removing it in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table similar to the one below

```
si  id  a   b   c   d   e
1   123 abc bcd abc def efg
2   234 bcd cde def efg fgh
3   345 cde efg efg abc ghi
```

What I want to do is find if the string "abc" is present in a row and if present remove it and copy the succeeding columns to its position i.e. in the first row "abc" is present in column A, so i want to remove it and move col B-E to Col A-D. In the 2nd row "abc" is not present, so this row should be retained as it is but in the 3rd row, "abc" is in Col D so it should be removed and "ghi" should be pasted in its location thus leaving col E empty.

I was able to do this using the `MATCH` but the catch here is `MATCH` only finds the first occurence but not the succeeding ones.

Is there a way to do using excel formulas and not vba.

Comment: You can't remove a cell and shift others with formulas.

Comment: @ScottCraner  I think you can.  You need to use the formula at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/NoBlanks.aspx but modify it so that abc comes out blank.  If I figure it out I will post an answer.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Chip's approach uses a helper column with a formula. I'm with Scott on this. A formula cannot change value of other cells.

Comment: @teylyn He says "I was able to do this using the MATCH" so he must not be explaining it correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot exit the data in place with formulas (mentioned in the comments) - but if you want a copy of the data that automatically removes the items updates the table whenever the original table is modified you can do that.  I will stick the result data below the input data but you could stick it on another sheet if you wanted to...

We start with this:

```
   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |
---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--
 1 |    si      id       a       b       c       d       e
 2 |     1     123     abc     bcd     abc     def     efg
 3 |     2     234     bcd     cde     def     efg     fgh
 4 |     3     345     cde     efg     efg     abc     ghi
 5 |
 6 |
 7 |
 8 |
 9 |
10 |
```

Step 1: in A6 put `=A1`

Step 2: Copy A6 to B6:G6, A7:A10 and B7:B10

Now the sheet looks like this:

```
   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |
---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--
 1 |    si      id       a       b       c       d       e
 2 |     1     123     abc     bcd     abc     def     efg
 3 |     2     234     bcd     cde     def     efg     fgh
 4 |     3     345     cde     efg     efg     abc     ghi
 5 |
 6 |    si      id       a       b       c       d       e
 7 |     1     123
 8 |     2     234
 9 |     3     345
10 |
```

Step 3: In C7 enter this array formula (remember to press Alt-Shift-Enter instead of just pressing Enter):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C2:$G2,1,SMALL(IF($C2:$G2<>"abc",COLUMN($C2:$G2)-2),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

Step 4: copy C7 to D7:G7 and C8:G9

Now the sheet looks like this:

```
   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |
---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+--
 1 |    si      id       a       b       c       d       e
 2 |     1     123     abc     bcd     abc     def     efg
 3 |     2     234     bcd     cde     def     efg     fgh
 4 |     3     345     cde     efg     efg     abc     ghi
 5 |
 6 |    si      id       a       b       c       d       e
 7 |     1     123     bcd     def     efg
 8 |     2     234     bcd     cde     def     efg     fgh
 9 |     3     345     cde     efg     efg     ghi
10 |
```

How it works:

`=IF($C2:$G2<>"abc",COLUMN($C2:$G2)-2)` generates an array of values with a number wherever a value is not abc and the value FALSE wherever a value is abc.  The `-2` is important because there are two header columns to the left of the data.

`=SMALL(IF($C2:$G2<>"abc",COLUMN($C2:$G2)-2),COLUMN(A1))` returns the nth smallest number in the array that was returned - it skips all the FALSE values.

`=INDEX($C2:$G2,1,SMALL(IF($C2:$G2<>"abc",COLUMN($C2:$G2)-2),COLUMN(A1)))` returns the value the location of that nth smallesst number - if there is no value there because of the filtered out items it returns an error

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C2:$G2,1,SMALL(IF($C2:$G2<>"abc",COLUMN($C2:$G2)-2),COLUMN(A1))),"")` returns the value and replaces the errors with a n empty cell.